# How can I get the prev/next key from an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, key, associative-array

I have an array of pages (`$menuItems`). I have it set up like this: `"pagename" => "pagelink"`. I have a variable (`$currentPage`) keeping track of what is the current page.

What I would like to accomplish is to take that variable of the page name, iterate through the list and determine which will be the next page (the next item from my array) and which will be the previous one.

I've set up a while loop trying to change the internal pointer to what the current page is. However, I believe I created an infinite loop, or something due to the fact that it won't load my results.

Here is an example of my code:

```
$menuItems = array (
    "Page one" => "index.php?page=page_one",
    "Page two" => "index.php?page=page_two",
    "Page three" => "index.php?page=page_three"
  )

$currentPage = "Page two";
$key = key($menuItems);

 while ($currentPage !== $key){
    next($menuItems);
 }
```

After I set the internal pointer to the correct array item I want to tell the next and prev using the `next()` and `prev()` functions. I haven't got far enough to implement that.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of input and desired output ? I'm not sure to understand what you try to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a lot simpler solution:

Just save all associative keys into an array with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), so that you can access the keys (array) with numerical keys.

So you will have an array like this (`$keys`):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Page one
    [1] => Page two
    [2] => Page three
)
```

Now you can just [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) your `$currentPage` in the keys to get the current key as numerical key and as you want add or subtract one (You also then want to check if the next/prev key exists, so that you don't have an undefined index).

```
<?php

    $menuItems = array (
        "Page one" => "index.php?page=page_one",
        "Page two" => "index.php?page=page_two",
        "Page three" => "index.php?page=page_three"
      );

    $keys = array_keys($menuItems);
    $currentPage = "Page two";
    $currentNumericalKey = array_search($currentPage, $keys);

    echo "Next item: " . $menuItems[$keys[$currentNumericalKey+1]] . "<br>";
    echo "Prev item: " . $menuItems[$keys[$currentNumericalKey-1]] . "<br>";

?>
```

output:

```
Next item: index.php?page=page_three
Prev item: index.php?page=page_one
```

Comment: This helped so much!! Thank you!

Comment: Nice. Playing devil's advocate though - this will trigger a PHP Notice (undefined offset) if you 'Page one' or 'Page three'. Just noting as it's probably a bounds-checking exercise for the OP.

Comment: @Darragh I said that in my answer: *(You also then want to check if the next/prev key exists, so that you don't have an undefined index)*

Comment: Sorry, you certainly did. I have a habit of just reading the code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$menuItems = array (
    "Page one" => "index.php?page=page_one",
    "Page two" => "index.php?page=page_two",
    "Page three" => "index.php?page=page_three"
  )

$currentPage = "Page two";

while (key($menuItems) !== $currentPage){
    next($menuItems);
} 

$nextPage = next($menuItems);
```